# Custom loss function in multilayered output model dependent on y_true of other outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I have a model having outputs like this

```
output_lya = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output_lya')(dropout)
output_log_NHI = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='output_log_NHI')(dropout)
output_log_bHI = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='output_log_bHI')(dropout)
output_Z_loc = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_Z_loc')(dropout)

and I have defined its losses like this-
combined_model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss={'output_lya': 'binary_crossentropy','output_log_NHI':"mean_squared_error",'output_log_bHI': 'mean_squared_error',  'output_Z_loc': 'mean_squared_error'},
    loss_weights={'output_lya': 1.0, 'output_log_NHI': 1.0, 'output_log_bHI': 1.0, 'output_Z_loc': 1.0},
)
```

this all works well, but now I want to define a cutom loss function for lets say for output_log_NHI which also takes in input the y_true values of the first output layer.

```
def masked_mean_sq_loss(labels_lya_train_batch):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        tf.print("Labels Lyα Train Batch:", len(labels_lya_train_batch))
        tf.print("Shape of y_true:", len(y_true))
        tf.print("Shape of y_pred:", len(y_pred))
        # Create a mask for instances where yc = 1
        #mask = tf.equal(labels_lya_train, 1)
        loss = K.square(y_pred - y_true)
        #masked_loss = tf.boolean_mask(loss, mask)
        mean_masked_loss = K.mean(loss)
        return mean_masked_loss
    return loss
```

its like a masked mean square loss but will affect the model only when the 1st binary classification labels are 1. now while compiling I want to input

```
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
combined_model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss={'output_lya': 'binary_crossentropy',**'output_log_NHI':masked_mean_sq_loss(labels_lya_train)**,'output_log_bHI': 'mean_squared_error',  'output_Z_loc': 'mean_squared_error'},
    loss_weights={'output_lya': 1.0, 'output_log_NHI': 1.0, 'output_log_bHI': 1.0, 'output_Z_loc': 1.0},
)
```

the labels_lya_train are the true labels corresponding to output_lya, now the problem is this label_lya_train are labels for the whole set of data, at a time I want to pass only the labels corresponding to the current batch. **The Y_true of the first output layer should be passed in the loss funtion of this layer**, How can I implement that ?

I tried to pass masked_mean_sq_loss(labels_lya_train_batch), to see if they name the labels corresponding batch, I tried to keep track of the current batch and pass labels but that is also difficult.